# Python canvas bigger size than screen

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I´m trying to figure out how to set the size of my tkinter canvas to bigger then actually my screen is. My screen is 1920x1280, if I set in the following code any higher numbers, the size never gets above this (and I want to do it due to huge drawing there).

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *


class Draw:

    def __init__(self, min, max):
        self.min = min
        self.max = max

    def draw(self):
        master = Tk()
        w = Canvas(master, width=2500, height=2500)
        #...
```

I also tried `master.geometry("2500x2500")` but that didn´t work either.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make windows larger than the physical screen. However, if your goal is to create a large drawing, you can do that without making the canvas physically large. The canvas widget is just a viewport into a much larger virtual drawing area.

For example, you can create a canvas that is only 400x400 pixels, yet draw an image that is 4000x4000. You can define the size of the virtual window by setting the `scrollregion` attribute to whatever size you want (up to a limit which I think is maybe around 64000x64000)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of your screen constraint, you cannot run 2500px * 2500px window on your 1920px * 1280px screen, if you try to run a window 1920px * 1280px on your screen, it would work.

This happens because your limits (2500px * 2500px) is too big for your monitor. The window tries to make 7250000 pixel on you 2457600 pixel screen!

So you would have to get a better screen possibly a 3k or 4k screen to run this.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way I could get this to work? It would be fine if I had to, for example, move with my window to see it all...

Comment: Someone else has answered this, thanks, would you mind upvoting my anwer